# xlstream can not open file

Tags: c++, excel

I am programmaticaly updating excel file using xlsstream library. When executed as console application, everything works fine. But I intend to use it as windows service to run independetly on user session and then it fails.

When written as service, it fails during opening an excel file with error: can not find excel file. The same situation occurs when that program is started by windows task manager. I suspect, it is dependend on being runned interactively. Any suggestions what can be a cause ?

Comment: Does the service user have the permissions to read the file? Is the path relative or absolute? Is it reachable if relative?

Comment: The service runs under local system account, path is absolute. When runned as console application, it works